# Animation on Page getting stuck upon back navigation

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

Windows Phone 7.5 app.

Designer has created Home.xaml in Blend that has 3 images(menu item) with storyboard animation.
The animation is very simple. Each image enlarges a little and returns to its normal size one after another.

It works fine on initial load. Now clicking one image takes me to another page.

**Issue:**
Now when I click back button(hardware) I go to my Home.xaml from navigated page, one of the image is kind of slanted as if it was in is stuck in middle of animation. The animation actaully goes fine for all buttons in cycle but one of the image(it is random which on) gets kind of stuck. Now this behavior is kind of random but can be replicated almost 95% time.

I am not sure how the animation fits in the page navigation cycle. I tried to explicitly stop the animation like below in OnNavigatedFrom

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
            sbBtn1.Stop();
            sbBtn2.Stop();
            sbBtn3.Stop();
            base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
}
```

It is kind of removing the initial problem but then it give another issue. Upon back navigation, the first image of the 3(that's the one that gets animated first upon page navigation) acts as if it is being zoomed-in a little.

**Edit:**

***I figured out the zoom-out issue of the first image. It was using 0.7 scalex/y instead of 0.75.***

If anyone can point me in right direction how to handle this animation please.

Here is [the sample](https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=64dcca1fdfad16e0&resid=64DCCA1FDFAD16E0!112&parid=64DCCA1FDFAD16E0!106&authkey=!AOIJGF6k4mM05_E) I created that replicates the issue. Get the **AnimationIssue** zip file.  Let me know if you are not able to download the sample.

How to reproduce:

1: Click one of the image to go to next page.
2: Then click hardware back button. You will see what I am talking. If not try step 1 and 2 two or three times.

Additional:

1: IF you comment out stop calls as I mentioned above, follow the steps above but this time notice the first Deserts image. You will see a slight zooming.

Hope someone will be able to point me in right direction. Thanks.

**Final question**
So what is wrong in my original version? Am I doing it right to Stop the animation in OnNavigatedFrom or should I do something else?

I am also thinking of explicitly call sbBtn1/2/3 .Begin in the page Loaded instead of relying on Triggers in the .xaml.

Comment: For some reason your animation must be restarting/continuing when resuming the app. How do you start the animation?

Comment: @xyzzer: It is started fro EventTrigger in .xaml. I understood that and so I forced stop in OnNavigateFrom. See my code block above and also my new edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with moving the code to Stop the animations in a separate method.

It wasn't just sufficient to stop the animation but also resetting some properites on which animation was performed.

OnNavigatedTo and From aren't just called upon naviagating via elements but also in the case say if your app is interrupted by a phone call or the phone goes to lockscreen.

I added a variable to keep track of conditions on when OnNavigatedTo/From are being called and depending on the case I called my Custom Animation Reset method.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same animation glitch in one of my Apps.

So the only workaround is to `Stop` all the Animation and use `Begin` again whenever Home.xaml is navigated to. Try this:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
     base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

     //Stop All the animations
     sbBtn1.Stop(); 
     sbBtn2.Stop(); 
     sbBtn3.Stop(); 

     //Start them all over again
     sbBtn1.Begin(); 
     sbBtn2.Begin(); 
     sbBtn3.Begin(); 
}
```